# Oracle - LRM-00109: could not open parameter file

Tags: oracle

Sometimes I get the following error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Aug 10 16:59:04 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup nomount;
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initimootstb.ora'
```

But I don't understand that issue because I have a spfile configured:

```
[oracle@serverdg dbs]$ srvctl config database -d mootstb
Database unique name: mootstb
Database name: mootdb
Oracle home: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
Oracle user: oracle
Spfile: +data/mootstb/parameterfile/spfile.279.1047485987 <<SPFILE EXISTS IN LOCATION
Domain:
```

Why the database is looking for init parameter file? just the spfile is not enough?

My workaround to resolv it is to create `initINSTANCE_NAME.ora` and put there a `spfile=+data/mootstb/parameterfile/spfile.279.1047485987` but I guess this is not a correct way to use the spfile.

Comment: You probably want to understand what happens _before_ that "sometimes" when you get this error. Presumably, at other times your server starts up just fine with the spfile.

Comment: Yes! Yesterday I've started the instance normally
Today is not starting... I've already seen this error before.. but how I said, I have the spfile configured correctly. Just the spfile is enough right?

Comment: Probably not, if it's corrupted or has incorrect permissions.

Comment: I wonder if something is *sometimes* not working with your Oracle ASM storage setup?  I haven't used ASM for years, so just a guess.  Also, does your error message directory name map to that ASM Spfile location?

Comment: How should Oracle know that there is an spfile at +Data/mootstb/... ?

Answer (score 2):

Your error message indicates that Oracle could not find the file "initimootstb.ora". This is the config file name for a database named "imootstb". Your config output shows your database name is actually "mootstb" (no "i"), so the most likely explanation I can see is that your ORACLE_SID environment variable is set incorrectly during startup. By creating the "missing" pfile you are just working around an incorrect environment configuration.

What is the result of using srvctl to start the database?

```
srvctl start database -d mootstb
```

Answer (score 2):

If all your input is correct then:

1. The database name is `mootdb`
2. The unique database name is `mootstb`
3. The instance name is `imootstb`

To start a database one can use `sqlplus`with the command

```
startup [PFILE=filename]
```

If one does not supply the PFILE argument then `sqlplus` looks up in the directory `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` for a file `spfile${ORACLE_SID}.ora` to start the database. If it does not find such a file it tries to open `init${ORACLE_SID}.ora` in the same directory. It it does not find this file it tries to open `init.ora`, but I am not sure about the latter. If it does not find one of these files it cannot start the database and issues the error message you showed us:

```
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file ...
```

The command `srvctl` is part of the Oracle RAC software and uses some configuration data that you can show with te appropriate command

```
srvctl config database -d UNIQUE_DB_NAME
```

I don't know where this configuration file is located. But in this file it usually stores where the spfile is located that should be used to start the database. This spfile is used by `srvctl` to start the database.

So both tools usually search in different location for the start file.
To solve this problem you can do what you have already donw

create a pfile for `sqlplus` that points to spfile in the ASM disk group.

```
$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init${ORACLE_SID}.ora
SPFILE=path_to_the_spfile
```

That is the correct way to solve the problem.